# How can I use ! with \ to wrap command in bash?

Tags: bash, string

I am in a situation that can not find a solution for my case.

I need to run a long command in bash, say:

```
node -p "const db = {1:1, 2:2};Object.keys(db).sort((a, b)=> a-b).map(Number).filter((n) => {return !isNaN(n)})"
```

Due to this command is relative long, I tried to use `\` to wrap my command.
Like this:

```
node -p "const db = {1:1, 2:2};Object.keys(db)\
.sort((a, b)=> a-b).map(Number).filter((n) => {return !isNaN(n)})"
```

But it complained that

```
bash: !isNaN: event not found
```

which I find similar to this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/277192/489079)

So I tried to replace `"` with `'`:

```
node -p 'const db = {1:1, 2:2};Object.keys(db)\
.sort((a, b)=> a-b).map(Number).filter((n) => {return !isNaN(n)})'
```

But this time, `\` is considered part of the command which is actually meaningless because I just want to wrap my command.

How can I solve this delemma?

Comment: You can temporarily turn off history expansion with `set +o histexpand` or `set +H`.

Comment: Does that code need to be passed as one line? I mean, if you use single quotes and remove the backslash, the string `node` gets would just have the newline right where it is, and you could just wrap the code in any way that works for the actual parser.

Comment: @ikk The code can be passed as several lines but which means I need to enter node REPL which is another environment instead bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a combination of single and double quotes, or just put the `\!` outside the quotes. In general using single quotes causes less surprises.

```
node -p "const db = {1:1, 2:2};Object.keys(db)\
.sort((a, b)=> a-b).map(Number).filter((n) => {return "\!"isNaN(n)})"

node -p "const db = {1:1, 2:2};Object.keys(db)\
.sort((a, b)=> a-b).map(Number).filter((n) => {return "'!'"isNaN(n)})"

node -p 'const db = {1:1, 2:2};Object.keys(db)'\
'.sort((a, b)=> a-b).map(Number).filter((n) => {return !isNaN(n)})'
```

Comment: Many thanks! That helps a lot!